# How to add new elements into my email template (django)

Tags: javascript, django, forms

i'm doing a form that will send an e-mail after completing the fields. The email must contains all the information wrote in the form, but in the forms i did a button to add more items, and this will appeart two new fields of "select component" and "quantity". How can i get the data from these fields that will be created after clicking into "add component" and put into my email?

my views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            type = form.cleaned_data['type']
            serialNumber = form.cleaned_data['serialNumber']
            itemNumber = form.cleaned_data['itemNumber']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            phase = form.cleaned_data['phase']
            capacity = form.cleaned_data['capacity']
            centerQuantity = form.cleaned_data['centerQuantity']
            componentQuantity = form.cleaned_data['componentQuantity']
            componentSelection = form.cleaned_data['componentSelection']
            commentary = form.cleaned_data['commentary']

            html = render_to_string('emails/email.html', {
                'type': type,
                'serialNumber': serialNumber,
                'item': itemNumber,
                'date': date,
                'phase': phase,
                'capacity': capacity,
                'centerQuantity': centerQuantity,
                'componentQuantity': componentQuantity,
                'componentSelection': componentSelection,
                'commentary': commentary,
            }
            
            ) 
            send_mail('ATENÇÃO', 'Message', 'no-reply@xxx.net', ['test@xxx.net'], html_message=html, fail_silently=False)
            
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = Form()
        
    return render(request, 'template.html', {
        'form': form 
    })
```

My html file:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h2> Engine Information</h2>
        <table>
            <form action="." method="POST" hx-post=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <td>{{form.type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Serial Number</th>
                        <td>{{form.serialNumber}}</td>
                        <th>or Material Number</th>
                        <td>{{form.itemNumber}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Manufactoring Date</th>
                        <td>{{form.date}}</td>
                        <th>Phase</th>
                        <td>{{form.phase}}</td>
                        <th>Capacity</th>
                        <td>{{form.capacity}}</td>
                        <th>Center Quantity</th>
                        <td>{{form.centerQuantity}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="component-form">
        <h2>Component</h2>
        <div class="parts-form">
            <table id="component">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select the component</th>
                        <td>{{form.componentSelection}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Component Quantity</th>
                        <td>{{form.componentQuantity}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <div id="form-added"></div>

            </table>
        </div>
        <button id="add-more" type="button">Add component</button>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Commentary</th>
                    <td>{{form.commentary}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        const AddMoreBtn = document.getElementById('add-more')
        AddMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', add_new_form)
        function add_new_form(event) {
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault()
            }
            //id
            const newId = document.getElementsByClassName('parts-form')
            const idIncrement = newId.length + 1
            //
            const formAdd = document.getElementById('form-added')
            //add new empty form
            var componentForm = document.getElementById('component').cloneNode(true)
            componentForm.setAttribute('class', 'parts-form')
            //id increment
            componentForm.setAttribute('id', `form-${idIncrement}`)
            formAdd.append(componentForm)
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

material_type = (
    ('material', 'Search with material'),
    ('serial', 'Search with serial number'),
)

component_type = (
    ('AIR FILTER', 'AIR FILTER'),
    ('ALUMINIUM FAN', 'ALUMINIUM FAN'),
    ('BEARING CAP DE', 'BEARING CAP DE')
)


class Form(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=material_type, initial="Select One Option")
    serialNumber = forms.CharField(label='Serial Number', required=False)
    itemNumber = forms.IntegerField(label='Item Number', required=False)
    date = forms.DateField(label='Manufactoring Date',widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ex: 10/05/2022'}))
    phase = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ex: Monophasic'}))
    capacity = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ex: 15cv'}))
    centerQuantity = forms.IntegerField(label='Center Quantity')
    componentSelection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=component_type, label='Component Selection')
    componentQuantity = forms.IntegerField(label='Component Quantity')
    componentSelection1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=component_type, label='Component Selection', required=False)
    componentQuantity1 = forms.IntegerField(label='Component Quantity', required=False)
    commentary = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":8, "cols":80}))
```

my email.html

```
<h2 id="title">Submission</h2>
<br>
<p>Type: {{type}}</p>
<p>Serial Number: {{serialNumber}}</p>
<p>Item: {{item}}</p>
<p>Manufactoring Date: {{date}}</p>
<p>Capacity: {{capacity}}</p>
<p>Center Quantity: {{centerQuantity}}</p>

<p>Component Quantity: {{componentQuantity}}</p>
<p>Component Selection: {{componentSelection}}</p>

<p>Commentary: {{commentary}}</p> 

<style>
    .title{
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling this scenario with simple django views and forms is not quite easy.

1. You need to set the input name attribute using the incremented index and the field name in your javascript.
2. Add the increment counter value to a special field in your form, so django knows how many fields have been added using javascript.
3. In the `__init__()` method of your form, you have to dynamically add the fields using the provided incremented index.
4. In your view you can then iterate over the dynamic fields using the incremented index as well.

Some helpful links:

- https://github.com/dabapps/django-forms-dynamic
- https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/